# How Can I fix my VS Code Programming Language (Logo/Icon) Not showing on a File

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image] Example. index.html, index.js. style.css

The file names should be able to identify the programming language and show an icon (JS, HTML, CSS logos) on the file.

Answer (score 1):

Install this extension

```
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme
```

and then **Set File Icon Theme** button will appear ,

click on it and select **Material Icon Theme**

I hope it was useful!

Answer (score 0):

Go To Vs Code's Setting (Gear logo at bottom left)
Search "VSCode Icons"
Once you search it, you'll find three options
`Breadcrumbs: Icons`,
`Outline: Icons`
Tick both of them and the third option will be
`Workbench: Icon Theme`
in your case, it will either be `None` or be `Minimal (Visual Studio Code)`
Just click on the tab and change it to `Seti (Visual Studio Code)`, Restart your VSCode, and all the icons will appear

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem press the gear icon at the bottom, press themes then press file icon theme dnd choose!